# How to prevent some url from execute which has some special charcters in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I wanted to prevent some Urls from execute which has some special character,

for Example:

```
http://www.testweb.com/StyleBundle/LayoutLoginCommon?v=<"luxehi%20>
http://www.testweb.com/StyleBundle/Common?v=<"luxehi%20>
```

I just do not want this Urls to execute as because it contains some special character in query string.

Because of this Url, this resources may be vulnerable to HTML injection.

How can I solve this issue in ASP.Net MVC

Comment: i think IIS will reject the bad url & %20 is just to replace " " character, so basically trim the value before assign to querystring.

Comment: Actually I have issue with < > sign, If this type sign are there in Url, No further execution should be done..

Comment: did you check whether [ValidateInput(false)] attribute is on your action or <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" /> is specify in ur webconfig or data anonotation on ur model properties [AllowHtml] 
    public string name {get;set;} ??

Comment: Actually this url is for loading .css file, And I want to prevent Url to execute if it found any vulnerable character.

Answer (score 1):

Use Encoding
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx

> HTML encoding makes sure that text is displayed correctly in the browser and not interpreted by the browser as HTML.

For example:

```
public string Common(string v)
{
    return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(v);
}
```